# Sinatra I can't use rake -T

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra, rake

I don't know why I can't use `rake -T` or `bundle exec rake -T`

```
# app.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/activerecord"

class App < Sinatra::Base
  #configuraciones
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
  set :session_secret, 'super secret'
  set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'
  set :layout, 'views/layouts'
  set :database, {adapter: "sqlite3", database: "data"}
  enable :sessions
  #before all requests
  before do
    headers['server'] = 'Ruby, Ubuntu'
  end
  #registro de helpers de la aplicacion
  helpers Sinatra::App::Helpers::Applicaction
  helpers Sinatra::App::Helpers::Filters
  #registro de helpers de routes
  helpers Sinatra::App::Helpers::ErrorHelper
  #registro de rutas
  register Sinatra::App::Routing::Home
  register Sinatra::App::Routing::Departamento
  register Sinatra::App::Routing::Provincia
  register Sinatra::App::Routing::Error
end
```

```
# Rakefile.rb

require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
require './app'
```

```
# config.ru

require_relative 'config/boot'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/app'

run App
```

This the error message:

```
PS C:\ruby\sinatra> bundle exec rake -T
WARNING: If you plan to load any of ActiveSupport's core extensions to Hash, be
sure to do so *before* loading Sinatra::Application or Sinatra::Base. If not,
you may disregard this warning.
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Sinatra::App
C:/ruby/sinatra/app.rb:18:in `<class:App>'
C:/ruby/sinatra/app.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/ruby/sinatra/Rakefile.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
PS C:\ruby\sinatra>
```

And here is the file structure:

[image]

***UPDATE*** 
 **First Change app.rb**

```
helpers Sinatra::App::Helpers::Application
```

**This is the helpers.rb**

```
 module Sinatra
  module App
    module Helpers
      module Application
        def load_css(csss)
          rpta = ''
          if defined? csss
            csss.each do |css|
              temp = '<link href="' + CONSTANTS[:static_url] + css + '.css" rel="stylesheet"/>'
              rpta = rpta + temp
            end
          end
          rpta
        end

        def load_js(jss)
          rpta = ''
          if defined? jss
            jss.each do |js|
              temp = '<script src="' + CONSTANTS[:static_url] + js + '.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'
              rpta = rpta + temp
            end
          end
          rpta
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have the same error

Comment: The error seems to refer to the line `helpers Sinatra::App::Helpers::Applicaction` – where is `Sinatra::App::Helpers::Applicaction` defined? Is that the correct namespace? Could you show its source?

Comment: What happens if you put `require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"` as first line in rakefile ?

Comment: Is `Applicaction` a typo?

Comment: @Stefan i'll show you just i forgot my code at home

Comment: @lacostenycoder i think i did that  but i will try again

Comment: @MarkThomas mmm could be a problem ill change it

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVE THAT I HAD TO ADD  IN app.rb

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/initializers/helpers.rb'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/initializers/filters.rb'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/helpers/error_helper.rb'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/routes/error.rb'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/routes/home.rb'
```

but i dont know why my boot.rb doesnt work

## config.ru

```
#!/usr/bin/env rackup
# encoding: utf-8

require_relative 'config/boot'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/app'

run App
```

## boot.rb

```
#registro de rutas
Dir["./routes/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
#registro de initializers
Dir["./config/initializers/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
#registro de modelos
Dir["./models/*_model.rb"].each {|file| require file }
#helpers
Dir["./helpers/*_helper.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```